# TcpListener won't lose connection

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm a noob to Visual Basic and .NET, so please excuse my maybe simple and stupid question.
I want to create a simple server client connection. This now works and my client can connect to the server. But if I close the client, the server still thinks, that the client is connected. Here my code:

```
Private server As TcpListener
Private serverPort As Integer = 8000
Private connectionMonitor As Tasks.Task
Private clientList As New List(Of Connection)

Public Structure Connection
    Dim client As TcpClient
End Structure

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    StartServer()
End Sub

Private Sub StartServer()
    server = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, serverPort)
    server.Start()
    server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AddressOf DoAcceptClient, server)
    Console.WriteLine("Server started")
    connectionMonitor = Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf DoMonitorConnections)
End Sub

Private Sub DoAcceptClient(result As IAsyncResult)
    ' Get the listener that handles the client request.
    Dim listener As TcpListener = CType(result.AsyncState, TcpListener)

    Dim client As TcpClient = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result)

    ' Process the connection here.
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected")
    Dim c As Connection = New Connection
    c.client = client
    clientList.Add(c)
End Sub

Private Sub DoMonitorConnections()
    Dim a As Integer = 0
    While True
        For index As Integer = 0 To clientList.Count - 1 Step 1
            Dim conn As Connection = clientList(index)
            If conn.client.Connected Then
                Console.WriteLine("Client still conncected" & a)
                Console.WriteLine(conn.client.Connected)
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Client connection lost")
                clientList.Remove(conn)
            End If
            a += 1
        Next
        ' throttle loop
        connectionMonitor.Wait(1000)
    End While
End Sub
```

In `DoMonitorConnections()` I check, if the client is still connected. Although the client application is closed, I still get the output "still connected", because the connected-property of the `TcpClient` is always True.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send something to Client and Catch the Error ... :

```
Private Sub DoMonitorConnections()
         While ...
            For index ...
            .
            .
                Try
                    Dim tmp(0) As Byte
                    conn.client.Client.Send(tmp)
                    Console.WriteLine("---Connected!---")
                Catch e As SocketException
                    Console.WriteLine("--Disconnected: error code {0}!", e.NativeErrorCode)
                End Try
            .
            .
        .
End Sub
```

Comment: This works, but I'll get an `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`, so after one disconnect, my server app doesn't recognize any new connections

Comment: I think that this code does not recognize more than one connection, have you tried more than one connection? Connect more Clients and Try `Console.WriteLine(index  & "Client still conncected" & a)`

Answer (score 0):

For sending/receiving sockets manually, you have to design a solid pattern so that both sides know when the transaction should be completed. When you're finished with the connection, both sides must call Shutdown, then call Disconnect.

After you get the hang of using sockets, definitely take a look at WCF as it makes everything much easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets only represent one end of the connection. If a connection is not closed gracefully (`Socket.Shutdown`, wait for 0 bytes and then call `socket.Close()`) it might take time before the other end detects the disconnect.

A solid indication of disconnect is when `Send` or `Receive` reports that 0 bytes have been transmitted. It's the best way to check if a connection is still active.